# GeoJson Feature dynamically don't appear on the layer

Tags: typescript, openlayers

I use the node modules librairy with TypeScript

In the first place i have a multiple of layer preload and i allocate one for only the Draw/Modificiation features

```
map = new Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [osm, swift, drawLayer],
        view: view,
        controls: defaults({attribution: false}).extend([attribution, new FullScreen()]),
    });

const drawLayer = new VectorLayer({
    source: new VectorSource({
        features: [],
        overlaps: true,
        format: new GeoJSON(),
    }),
    visible: true,
    style: (feature) => selectSingleClick(feature, ""),
    properties: {olLayer: 'drawLayer', lyrs: {}},
});
```

My logic is to get my data from an api when the user want to edit the Geometry. Then i load the GeoJson like this.

```
const myGeoJsonFeatures: Feature<Geometry>[] = new GeoJson().readFeatures(data.html);
vLayers["drawLayer"].getSource().addFeatures(myGeoJsonFeatures);
```

When the layers is changed, i got the feature in getFeatures() but i have nothing on my screen.

I looked in the documentation or on some forum to fix this but with no results.

Thanx for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolve the problem by hide all the layers and delete the function useGeographic().

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).